# How can update a object state in inputs ? (React js Hooks)

Tags: reactjs

I'm new in React and I saw a lot of topics about updateo bject state but in my case I continue with erros.

I have a object useSate and I want update every time my input changes.
I have tried the spread operator.

My state :

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    topic: {
      coins: 0,
      money: 0,
      cash: 0,
    }
 })
```

my handle funtion :

```
const handleMoney = (e) => {
      setInputs(prevState =>({
        inputs:{
          ...prevState.inputs,
          coins: e.target.value
        }
      }))
}
```

And my form ( is from react boostrap):

```
           <Form.Control
             min={0}
             type="number"
             value={inputs.coins}
             onChange={handleMoney }
           />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code [click to see](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-ramanujan-40jpy?file=/src/App.js) .If its help please mark as answer

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    toggle: false,
    topic: {
      coins: 0,
      money: 0,
      cash: 0,
    }
  });

  const onHandleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setState(pre => ({
      ...pre,
      topic: {
        ...pre.topic,
        [name]: value
      }
    }))
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Coins : {state.topic.coins} </p>
      <p>Money : {state.topic.money} </p>
      <p>Cash : {state.topic.cash} </p>
      <input type="number" name='coins' onChange={onHandleChange} value={state.topic.coins} />
      <input type="number" name='money' onChange={onHandleChange} value={state.topic.money} />
      <input type="number" name='cash' onChange={onHandleChange} value={state.topic.cash} />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: If it's helpful for you please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const handleMoney = (e) => {
    setInputs({
     ...inputs,
      inputs['topic']['coin'] = e.target.value
  })
```

Otherwise You can use

```
    const handleMoney = (e) => {
      const newInput = {...inputs}
      newInput['topic']['coin'] =e.target.value
      setInputs(newInput)
    })
```

And form is

```
       <Form.Control
       min={0}
       type="number"
       value={inputs.topic?.coins}
       onChange={()=>handleMoney() }
       />
```